# Trying to increment an age in React

Tags: reactjs

Believe that my problem lies within the incrementAge function or by setting age value within p tag. Im new to React and trying to figure out how to use state and manipulate it

```
class MyNewComponet extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            age: this.incrementAge
        }
    }
    incrementAge = () => {
        this.setState({
            age : this.state.age +=1
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               <fieldset>
                   <h1>Doe, Jane</h1>
                   <p>Age: {this.state.age = 45}</p>
                   <button onClick={this.incrementAge}>Birthday Button</button>

                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h1>Smith, John</h1>
                    <p>Age: {this.state.age = 88}</p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind a single `state.age` variable to multiple people. Also, you must not directly assign values like `this.state.age=something` and instead use `this.setState` function

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple mistakes, mind the comments with `FIX`:

```js
class MyNewComponet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // age: this.incrementAge
            // FIX: You need a specific initial age, not the function
            age: 45
        }
    }
    incrementAge = () => {
        this.setState({
            // age: this.state.age += 1
            // FIX: increment the age by +, not +=
            age: this.state.age + 1
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <h1>Doe, Jane</h1>
                    {/* <p>Age: {this.state.age = 45}</p> */}
                    {/* FIX: You cannot assign this.state.age there, use the value instead */}
                    <p>Age: {this.state.age}</p>
                    <button onClick={this.incrementAge}>Birthday Button</button>

                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h1>Smith, John</h1>
                    {/* <p>Age: {this.state.age = 88}</p> */}
                    {/* FIX: If you need another age state, set it in this.state */}
                    <p>Age: 88</p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the FIX comments, I appreciate it.